# iPhone, how do I toggle my Edit button for my table then to Done and back to Edit?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've added my edit button

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self 
        action:@selector(editNavButtonPressed)] autorelease];
```

But I don't seem to be able to turn it to Done and back, the console says its Null

```
-(IBAction)editNavButtonPressed
{
//[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
BOOL editing = !self.tableView.editing;
NSLog(@"tile=#%@#", self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title);

if ([self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit")]) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
} else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");

}
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = !editing;
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = (editing) ? NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done") : NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
[self.tableView setEditing: editing animated: YES];
```

}

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use the `-[UIViewController editButtonItem]`, it will correctly toggle state from Edit/Done, and will also toggle the editing mode on the `UIViewController` itself.

Setup with something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
}
```

You can then override `-[UIViewController setEditing:animated:]` to get notified immediately when the editing mode is toggled.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    // Add your custom code here
}
```

Or you can query the `UIViewController` for it's current editing state like so:

```
if ([self isEditing]) {
    // Do something editing like
} else {
    // Do whatever is not editing like.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change button style or use builtin self.editButtonItem;

check this - [How to change UIBarButtonItem's type in UINaviagationBar at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648244/how-to-change-uibarbuttonitems-type-in-uinaviagationbar-at-runtime)

Cheers,
Krzysztof Zabłocki

Comment: Yes but I also need to determine what the button is set too now.  I did find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020716/rename-standard-edit-button-in-tableview but the setEditing function is never called.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

In your tableViewController add an outlet and action for your edit button:

```
@IBOutlet var editButton:UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func editTapped() {
    if(self.tableView.isEditing){
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated:true)
        editButton.title = "Edit"
    }else{

        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated:true)
        editButton.title = "Done"
    }
}
```

Add a barButtonItem to the tableViewController in storyboard, then connect up the button's referencing outlet and sent action.