# editButtonItem Does Not Work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view inside a UIViewController with editing enabled for deleting rows. Swiping from the right lets me delete rows and I have the edit button on the navigation bar but it doesn't actually do anything except switch from saying Edit to Done.

Here is how I'm creating my table view.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if sharedCart.shoppingCart.isEmpty {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

        isEmptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width / 2, self.view.frame.height / 2, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
        isEmptyLabel.center = self.view.center
        isEmptyLabel.text = "Your cart is empty."
        isEmptyLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        isEmptyLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        isEmptyLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 20.0)

        self.view.addSubview(isEmptyLabel)
    } else {
        isEmptyLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        total = 0

        let editItem = self.editButtonItem()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editItem

        tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: .Grouped)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "passCartCell")
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CartFooterView", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "cartFooter")

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

And I use these methods for editing.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        sharedCart.shoppingCart.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        self.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: and the issue is ???

Comment: Sorry I'm not totally clear on what the issue is. What do you want the edit button to do? Enable editing on you tableView?

Comment: I want the edit button to enable editing.

Comment: So your issue is the row wasn't deleted successfully?

Comment: I'm able to delete rows by swiping but not with the edit button on navigation bar. When I press the edit button, it doesn't enable the editing in the table view

Comment: Side-note: **NEVER EVER** call delegate methods on purpose including  `should`, `will` or `did`

Comment: You need to override `setEditing:animated:` in the UIViewController, and set the editing flag of the table view accordingly.  UITableViewController does this automatically; UIViewController doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone, how do I toggle my Edit button for my table then to Done and back to Edit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872127/iphone-how-do-i-toggle-my-edit-button-for-my-table-then-to-done-and-back-to-edi)

Answer (score 5):

Cedric Michael's answer almost works, but it disables `editButtonItem`'s automatic, animated toggling between the **Edit** and **Done** title & associated state. The better fix is this:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

Also, if you want to hide the **Edit** button for an empty shopping cart, it would be better form to set `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem` in `viewDidLoad()` and simply set `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.isHidden` to true or false in `viewWillAppear()` according to the shopping cart.

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 3**, implement this in your **UIViewController** class:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if(editing && !tableView.isEditing){
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }else{
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

(This is not necessary for a UITableViewController class).

You should also set your **editButtonItem** **before**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
}
```

Then it works! ツ

Answer (score 1):

In order for your table to toggle between edit and normal mode on button tap you need to implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        if self.tableView.editing {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
        }
        else{
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
        }
    }
```

And on button tap or IBAction of button :)

```
@IBAction func editButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var button =  sender as! UIButton
    if button.titleLabel!.text! == "Edit" {
        self.tableView.editing = true
        button.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else{
        self.tableView.editing = false
        button.setTitle("Edit", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Just realised you have bar button item on navigation bar rather then plain UIButton :)

So you can modify the IBAction as below :) Make sure the you select System Item for UIBarButton item as Custom and set the title as Edit

```
@IBAction func editButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button =  sender as! UIBarButtonItem
    if button.title! == "Edit" {
        self.tableView.editing = true
        button.title = "Done"
    }
    else{
        self.tableView.editing = false
        button.title = "Edit"
    }
}
```

This should do the job :) Happy coding :)

Comment: downvoter please leave your comment below if you had one while downvoting